# svg miterlimit на две отдельные линии

Tags: javascript, svg

Есть 2 линии с 4-мя точками: одна линия = 2 точки
Необходимо применить один miterlimit [stroke-miterlimit-svg](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-miterlimit) сразу к 2-ум линиям так, как он применяется по умолчанию к одной.. Как написать правильно такой алгоритм на JavaScript для построения таких конечных точек? Помогите, пожалуйста..

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wky7u4jc/)

```js
(function(win, doc) {
  var svg = doc.getElementById('svg');
  var path1Element = doc.getElementById('p1');
  var path2Element = doc.getElementById('p2');
  var point1;
  var point2;
  var path1;
  var path2;
  
  point1 = [{x:5, y:10}, {x:15, y:5}];
  point2 = [{x:15, y:5}, {x:25, y:10}];
  path1 = 'M' + point1[0].x + ',' + point1[0].y + 'L' + point1[1].x + ',' + point1[1].y;
  path2 = 'M' + point2[0].x + ',' + point2[0].y + 'L' + point2[1].x + ',' + point2[1].y;
  
  path1Element.setAttributeNS(null, 'd', path1);
  path2Element.setAttributeNS(null, 'd', path2);
})(window, document);
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 38 30" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg">
<path stroke="black" fill="none" stroke-linejoin="miter" id="p1"
        d="M0, 0 L0, 0" />
<path stroke="black" fill="none" stroke-linejoin="miter" id="p2"
        d="M0, 0 L0, 0" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

`stroke-miterlimit` изменяет скосы для path: [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/diman_ych_/ochm1fLd/5/)

В вашем случае либо делать через 1 path для двух линий, либо костылить, смещая линии на 0,5: [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/diman_ych_/am5nwL07/3/)

Comment: а что делать если угол острый а не тупой?